# Android: Accessing system dictionary

Tags: android, localization, spell-checking

My goal is to validate OCR results.

Android offers a SpellCheckerSession inferface to check for word suggestions. That feature ought to be backed up by a localized dictionary. Is there a way to gain access to that dictionary? Loading a huge UserDictionary myself and keeping dozens of them up-to-date for proper localisation doesn't seem like a good idea.

I scanned the documentation over and over again, but I must be missing something. Here is an ideal scenario (that unfortunately doesn't exist) :

```
Dictionary d = SystemDictionary.forLocale("fr-ca");
d.contains(word);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do something similar.  The solution I came up with was to use the SpellCheckerSession and check if it came up with an exact match in onGetSentenceSuggestions.

```js
public class SpellChecker implements SpellCheckerSessionListener {
    public SpellChecker(Activity a)
    {
        final TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager) a.getSystemService(
                Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);
                SpellCheckerSession scs = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, null, this, true);
                TextInfo[] tia = {new TextInfo("trewgjj"), new TextInfo("great")};
                scs.getSentenceSuggestions(tia, 3);
    }
    @Override
    public void onGetSuggestions(SuggestionsInfo[] results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onGetSentenceSuggestions(SentenceSuggestionsInfo[] results) {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
            // Returned suggestions are contained in SuggestionsInfo
            for (int j = 0; j < results[i].getSuggestionsCount(); ++j) {
                SuggestionsInfo si =  results[i].getSuggestionsInfoAt(j);
                if ((si.getSuggestionsAttributes() & SuggestionsInfo.RESULT_ATTR_IN_THE_DICTIONARY) != 0)
                    Log.d("", "EXACT MATCH FOUND"); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only issue is if you also want to validate words against the user defined dictionary. I don't believe those are included in this spell checker framework so you may have to check against those words manually.